# Overview of Pitts & McCullough (1943) "A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity"

Tags: computational-modeling, theoretical-neuroscience

Is there a good tutorial or simplified overview of the paper, '[Logical calculus for nervous activity' (McCullough & Pitts, 1943)](http://cns-classes.bu.edu/cn550/Readings/mcculloch-pitts-43.pdf)?

<sub>**Reference**

McCullough, W. S., & Pitts, W. (1943). A logical calculus of the ideas immanent in nervous activity. *The Bulletin of Mathematical Biophysics, 5*(4), 115–133. Retrieved from http://cns-classes.bu.edu/cn550/Readings/mcculloch-pitts-43.pdf.</sub>

Comment: You have at least three seperate accounts: [1](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/3664/zeph), [2](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/4520/zeph), [3](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/4538/zeph). All of them are unregistered, if you register an account then we can merge all of them together which will allow you to more fully participate in this StackExchange.

Comment: I created an account, but not sure how to link the older questions to it. Sorry about the unintentional spam, I was being lazy about creating an account.

Comment: I will look into having your previous accounts merged into this one. Thank you for registering.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is! Check out [Marsalli's module from The Mind Project's curriculum](http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/modOverview.php?modGUI=212) and let me know if it works for you. It seems McCullough and Pitts' paper was important enough to be cited very many times, so there are probably several other options out there for you.

<sub>**Reference**

Marsalli, M. McCulloch-Pitts neurons. *The Mind Project: Curriculum.* Retrieved from http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/modOverview.php?modGUI=212.</sub>

Comment: Their paper is cited by many as the [first introduction of deterministic finite state automata](http://egtheory.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/minimizing-finite-state-automata/) into computer science (although in my opinion some work in idustrial engineering preceeds this). Thus it is very important for the history of CS; I don't think it is nearly as important for neuroscience, unfortunately :(.

Comment: Unfortunately in the sense that neuroscience has overlooked McCullough and Pitts (1943), or in the sense that it makes this a rather off-topic question?

Comment: I did see it cited in this cognitive neuroscience tutorial paper - http://ccn.psych.purdue.edu/papers/ccn_in_press.pdf

@Nick That is a good point. I'd be curious to understand the same.